# expectation & variance of square of non-standard normal distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Let $A \sim Normal(k, 1)$ (ie. with mean $k$ and variance $1$). Let $B = A^2$. The first step is to express the CDF of $B$ in terms of the CDF $S_X(x)$ of the standard normal distribution (with mean $0$ and variance $1$).

That part I think is fine. I said the CDF of $B$ is expressed by: $P(B \leq b) = P(A^2 \leq b) = P(-\sqrt{b} \leq A \leq \sqrt{b}) = S_X(\sqrt{b} - k) - S_X(-\sqrt{b} - k)$.

The next part is to find the expectation and variance of $B$. I am not seeing how to do that short of evaluating some unappealing integrals. How would one go about doing this?

My class has not yet introduced the Chi-squared distribution, though I am aware this question is related to that. If possible, answers not using the Chi-squared distribution would be more helpful.

Edit: haven't covered moment-generating functions yet, either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $E(B) = E((Z+k)^2)$, where $Z$ ~ $N(0, 1)$. Do you know $E(Z^4)$?

Comment: I think we can also solve for $Var(A) = E(B) - E(A)^2$, which doesn't involve $A^4$, and that would lead us to an answer of $1 + k^2$ for $E(B)$. However, I think the variance calculation for $B$ might involve $E(Z^4)$ as you suggested. would you mind elaborating? Thank you!

Comment: Ah, thats even faster and yields $E(B) = 1+k^2$. Now $Var(B) = E(B^2) - E(B)^2 = E((Z+k)^4) - (1+k^2)^2$ and using $E(Z)=0=E(Z^3)$ we obtain $E((Z+k)^4) = E(Z^4) + 6k^2E(Z^2) + k^4 = 3+6k^2+k^4$.

Comment: I see now, thank you so much! Also, last question -- why is $E(B)=E((Z+k)^2) $, and not $E(B)=E((Z-k)^2)$? I'm probably just messing up some translating someplace?

Comment: We have $E(Z+k) = k$, so it cannot be $Z-k$ :) as $A$ has mean $k$, too, and $Z-k$ has mean $-k$.

Comment: perfect! Thank you very much! @Stockfish